# How use return with page.goto in Puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, return, puppeteer

I'm using `return` inside `await page.goto` in [Puppeteer](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer) and I don't know why  `return` doesn't work. Here's a code sample:

This line below doesn't work:

```
return elements // return data collected
```

Full code:

```
 /* --- Lógica para coletar os dados de cada página --- */
        await page.goto(url, { waitUntil: 'networkidle0' })
        let data = await page.evaluate(() => {
            const root = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('tr.team'))
            let elements = root.map((e) => ({
                id: Math.random().toString(16).slice(2),
                date: new Date().toJSON().slice(0, 10).replace(/-/g, '/'),
                teamName: e.querySelector('td.name').innerText,
                wins: e.querySelector('td.wins').innerText,
                loses: e.querySelector('td.losses').innerText,
            }))
            // console.log('console.log(elements)') // DEBUG
            console.log('return elements executado') // DEBUG
            return elements // return data collected
        })
```

How do make **return** work?

Comment: Return a `Promise`, that way you can `await` for your data: `return Promise.resolve(elements);`

Comment: @PeterThoeny it won't change anything

Comment: How do you know that return doesn't work? You don't do anything with the data

Comment: Your question is about `page.evaluate()`, not `page.goto()` I assume. Code looks fine to me. If it [doesn't work](https://web.archive.org/web/20180124130721/http://importblogkit.com/2015/07/does-not-work/), please provide a [mcve]. What does "not working" entail, exactly? What were you expecting to happen, what happened? Was there an error? If so, what? Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: By the way, logs inside of `evaluate` go to the browser console, so unless you're adding a listener or have opened devtools, you won't see those.

Comment: Thanks for the help, guys @ggorlen and others I'm a student and happy to stay here. Problem solved! ;)

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. My `let` in `.push` was wrong.

After this block code:

```
return elements // return data collected
```

My `.push` stay targeted to `dataFromPages.push(...elements)`.

My array `return` was empty. This is a beginner wrong.

I put the right way, `dataFromPages.push(...data)` with `data` let.

Thank you guys.

Full correct code to help community:

```
for (let i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
        let url = urls[i]
        console.log(`Coletando dados da url: ${chalk.underline(url)}`)

        /* --- Lógica para coletar os dados de cada página --- */
        await page.goto(url, { waitUntil: 'networkidle0' })
        let data = await page.evaluate(async () => {
            const root = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('tr.team'))
            let elements = root.map((e) => ({
                id: Math.random().toString(16).slice(2),
                date: new Date().toJSON().slice(0, 10).replace(/-/g, '/'), //TODO: Colocar a HORA também
                teamName: e.querySelector('td.name').innerText,
                wins: e.querySelector('td.wins').innerText,
                loses: e.querySelector('td.losses').innerText,
            }))
            return elements // return data collected
        })
        dataFromPages.push(...data)
    }
```